# How to set non-linear step in yAxis on Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'd like to show chart in this way:

- Higher (in 1 tick from five to max)
- 5
- 4
- 3
- 2
- 1
- 0
- Lower (in 1 tick from min to 0)

I tried use min/max or floor/ceiling,but it doesn't works

```
    yAxis: {
      floor: 0,
      ceiling: 5,
      title: {
      text: 'Value'
      }
    },
```

I make example here: http://jsfiddle.net/4NV2J/2/

Could you please give me directions?

Comment: Have you tried to use `minPadding` and `maxPadding`?

Comment: Something like http://jsfiddle.net/4NV2J/3/ ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan, I tried it. I'd like to get the same heights of ticks from 4 to 5 and from 5 to 85. Is it possible?

Comment: @PawełFus, not sure that it is what I'm looking for

Comment: @Ksandr in this scenario not, only logarithmic do this, but it works in different way. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.type

Comment: @SebastianBochan, may be is there any way to draw point with value that over 5 on next line and hide next line value so it'll draw within chart?

Comment: Ok, could you show simple mockup (image) how this should looks like? Thanks.

Comment: @PawełFus Something like [this](http://cl.ly/image/270D2Z0g241V). I think I can archive it if I programmatically set values that higher than 5 at 5.1 and in tooltip formatter write if value 5.1 than ">5"

Comment: @PawełFus but it will be better if I have opportunity to set "y" separately from value

Comment: See my answer, I think that should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need something like 'scale break', which isn't supported (yet) by Highcharts.

Workaround is to set some rounded value, and use different property for point to display in tooltip: http://jsfiddle.net/4NV2J/6/

You can also add `label.formatter` for yAxis, to make chart easier to read.

And code:

```
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Y axis'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    yAxis: {
        tickInterval: 1,
        min: -1,
        max: 6,
        title: {
            text: 'Value'
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                if(this.isFirst) {
                    return '< 0';
                } else if (this.isLast) {
                    return '> 5';
                } else {
                     return this.value;   
                }
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat:  '<span style="color:{series.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.options.trueValue}</b><br/>'   
    },
    series: [{
        data: [{
            y: 3,
            trueValue: 3
        }, {
            y: 4,
            trueValue: 4 
        }, {
            y: -1,
            trueValue: -4 
        }, {
            y: 6,
            trueValue: 40
        }]        
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Paweł. It is exactly what I tried to archive!